# How to group set of records in log table based on status changes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a large activity table that contains all actions taken on a case.  some of these actions change the status of the case.  Some actions do not change the status of the case, and essentially should be the status of the previous non-null record.
sample:

```
caseID | datetime | action | status
1        1/1/2020      a     OPEN
1        1/2/2020      B     NULL
1        1/3/2020      G     CLOSED
1        1/5/2020      T     REOPEN
1        1/6/2020      H     NULL
1        1/7/2020      H     NULL
1        1/9/2020      G     CLOSED
1        1/10/2020     J     CLOSED
1        1/15/2020     P     CLOSED
```

the output i am trying to achieve is to group and attach a "session" number to the set of dates that contain the date range from open OR reopen TO close.  The idea here is that if the dateto is NULL, then that is the current status:

```
CaseID | status | datefrom | dateto | session
1        OPEN     1/1/2020   1/3/2020   1
1        CLOSED   1/3/2020   1/5/2020   1
1        REOPEN   1/5/2020   1/9/2020   2
1        CLOSED   1/9/2020   NULL       2
```

i am using SQL 2014 enterprise edition and have been wracking my brain on this for days...any help would be much appreciated.  I have found some hints on stackoverflow, but nothing that fully satisfies the needed output.

EDIT: here is a better example of the data:

```
caseID | datetime | action | status
1        1/1/2020      a     OPEN
1        1/2/2020      B     REOPEN
1        1/3/2020      G     CLOSED
1        1/5/2020      T     REOPEN
1        1/6/2020      H     NULL
1        1/7/2020      H     NULL
1        1/9/2020      G     CLOSED
1        1/10/2020     J     CLOSED
1        1/15/2020     P     CLOSED
1        1/16/2020     P     WORKABLE
1        1/17/2020     P     NULL
1        1/18/2020     P     WORKABLE
1        1/19/2020     P     WORKABLE
1        1/20/2020     P     CLOSED
1        2/1/2020      o     NULL
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
CaseID | status | datefrom | dateto | session
1        OPEN     1/1/2020   1/3/2020   1
1        CLOSED   1/3/2020   1/5/2020   1
1        REOPEN   1/5/2020   1/9/2020   2
1        CLOSED   1/9/2020   1/16/2020  2
1        WORKABLE 1/16/2020  1/20/2020  3
1        CLOSED   1/20/2020  NULL       3
```

Comment: How do you define "session"?

Comment: session is defined as the timeframe between when a case is in a non-closed status (open, reopen, workable) to when it is closed.  the next session will begin when the status changes again from closed to open/reopen/workable.

Answer (score 1):

This answers the original version of the question.

I'm not sure if this meets all your requirements, but it produces the results you specify:

- Factor out the `NULL` values.
- Assign session based on the number of "open"s or "reopens" up to a row
- Aggregate:

So:

```
select caseid, session, status, min(datetime),
       lead(min(datetime)) over (partition by caseid order by min(datetime))
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when status in ('OPEN', 'REOPEN') then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by caseid order by datetime) as session
      from t
      where status is not null
     ) t
group by caseid, session, status
order by caseid, min(datetime);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b1aed89b3efeb8d95a96ea9a9f5f4970) is a db<>fiddle illustrating that this interpretation works for the data you have provided.

Comment: this is awesome!  thank you.  After querying a few other cases, i am also seeing where there are non-CLOSED statuses back to back, so in your example, if you replaced the second row's status of NULL to REOPEN, you will see that for session 1, there is an OPEN, REOPEN, and then a CLOSED.  I would like to actually skip that particular REOPEN.